# Scroll for more script -- How?

Tags: jquery, load, scroll

If you look on http://soup.io or http://hashtags.org, and you scroll all the way down, you'll see how the page automatically loads MORE INFORMATION as you get to the bottom.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [Scroll Event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/scroll), making an [Ajax call](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) and appending the resulting HTML to the content of a DIV.

Here's some more information on how to do it: [load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)